# Perfect Scrollbar not showing/updating the scrollbar in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Perfect Scrollbar (https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) to style the scrollbar. The issue is when I open my modal, the scrollbar doesn't appear/update to the new styled one. It only appears after I start scrolling the content. I found a similar problem:

"If it appears when starting scrolling, it's very likely to be a timing issue. Please ensure that PS' update method is called after the div is filled with content. I'm not sure which modal is being used, but there could be a callback to handle it."

https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/263

However, when I try to put `https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar` into the code from remodal's script the scrollbar still doesn't update and doesn't appear.

*EDIT* Please see problem here (http://imdarrien.com/#) Press on any of the projects.

```
* Opens a modal window
* @public
*/
Remodal.prototype.open = function() {

var remodal = this;
var id;

// Check if the animation was completed
if (remodal.state === STATES.OPENING || remodal.state === STATES.CLOSING) {
  return;
}

id = remodal.$modal.attr('data-' + PLUGIN_NAME + '-id');

if (id && remodal.settings.hashTracking) {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  location.hash = id;
}

if (current && current !== remodal) {
  halt(current);
}

current = remodal;

lockScreen();
remodal.$bg.addClass(remodal.settings.modifier);
remodal.$overlay.addClass(remodal.settings.modifier).show();
remodal.$wrapper.show().scrollTop(0);
remodal.$modal.focus();

syncWithAnimation(
  function() {
    setState(remodal, STATES.OPENING);
  },

  function() {
    setState(remodal, STATES.OPENED);
  },

  remodal);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01n947d0/ (the fiddle doesn't replicate the problem exactly, not sure why scrollbar is not appearing when modal is open). Here is someone's fiddle with an older version of perfect scrollbar doing its thing (http://codepen.io/Labirintami/pen/OPRWWY)

*EDIT* This is the code to intialize prefectScrollbar

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {   
    $('.remodal').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true, maxScrollbarLength: 200});   
  });
```

`$(".remodal").perfectScrollbar('update');`

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the code you post, there aren't nothing about perfectScrollbar initialize. Share the correct code

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It's at the bottom of the fiddle javascript panel. I updated OP so you can find it. :)

Comment: You are initializing perfectScrollbar on document ready, but not after fill modal contents. With this code I don't know when you initialize and when you update. It's not trivial, it's important to know when you make these actions, because, if there's a milisecond of gap it doesn't works.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude This is the modal plugin I'm using (https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal/blob/master/dist/remodal.js) From what I understand, when you click on a link marked with a data-id it'll apply `.remodal-wrapper` to the .remodal and display it's content. I've tried adding     `$(".remodal").perfectScrollbar('update');` just before it adds that wrapper class.

Comment: Try **after** `remodal.$wrapper.show().scrollTop(0);` and don't update scrollbar, create scrollbar instead. If it doesn't works yet, try wrapping the instance of the scrollbar inside a `setTimeout();`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That worked! I put `  $('.remodal').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true, maxScrollbarLength: 200});` after `remodal.$wrapper.show().scrollTop(0);`. Thank you so much!

Comment: So, I put it as an answer. Please, mark it as the valid answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talk in comments, you must to initialize scrollbar after content shows.

```
 remodal.$wrapper.show().scrollTop(0);
 $('.remodal').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true, maxScrollbarLength: 200});
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this problem back up but I just noticed that when you switch from one open modal to another modal, the scrollbar disappears again!